# setFrame - I need some clarification for this

Tags: iphone, uibutton, cgrectmake

I have a code for programmatic creation of buttons, and here it is

```
UIImage *aroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"locBar.png"];
    UIImage *aroundImageDown = [UIImage imageNamed:@"locBarColor.png"];
    UIButton *aroundButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [aroundButton setFrame:CGRectMake(240, 369, 80, 48)];  
    [aroundButton setImage:aroundImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [aroundButton setImage:aroundImageDown forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [aroundButton setImage:aroundImageDown forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [aroundButton addTarget:self action:@selector(aroundMe) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    
    [self.view addSubview:aroundButton];
```

so now i have set the frame for the button, but what if this app is seen on iPhone4 in 640x960. Then i have different images "locBar@2x.png and locBarColor@2x.png" and they should be with a different CGRectMake, or should they? My question is how do I set up a button for both resolutions, and do that programmatically .

Comment: no prob whatever size given the pictures automatically adjusted in retina or simple iPhone display. but make sure the double size image with @2x is exist

Comment: so my code is OK to use it for Iphone5>;What about the @HChouhan02 's answer?

Comment: he is not clear the question. and make sure it's not iPhone 5. it's a screen difference simple and retina like iPhone 2,3 ,3G Vs iPhone 4, 4s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's automatic :)
ios will load the @2x version if available and if the device has a x2 scale.
The frame is in point, not in pixel.

Look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html)  in Points Versus Pixels

Comment: so you are saying my code is OK as it is. I have the @2x images, and there is nothing i should change for the iPhone5

Comment: Arg, I don't for iPhone 5, I can't see the future :)

Comment: i meant iPhone4 got confused sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

If you include a high-resolution version of the image with the same name, but with @2x before the extension,iOS will automatically choose the correct resolution according to display resolution, as long as you use the [UIImage imageNamed:] function, or set the image in IB.

Answer (score -1):

you have to put the condition and then according to the screen size make button frame and give them images.